# Angular / Ionic 4: trigger change detection when coming back from another page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm new to Angular and Ionic 4, building an Ionic app. I have the following situation:

There are 2 components inside a page. I'm in component A and navigate forward to component B, then open a Modal and update the database (SQLite).

I need to use the new values saved in the database to update the template of the component A. But when I click the back button on component B (to go back to A), I'm not able to read the database, because it seems this event doesn't trigger anything on component A.

I tried to read the database inside an onDoCheck, but it entered in a loop.

I tried to make component B write a value on a singleton and then make component A check for it in the onDoCheck, but it didn't work either.

I tried to call a ApplicationRef.tick() in the confirm of the Modal. But it didn't trigger anything on A.

I didn't find a way to capture the "back event" from component B to A. If I'd found, I would try to call the ApplicationRef.tick() on that event...

It guess it is something very basic, and I'm probably missing some important Angular concepts.
Can anyone please given me some light in here?

Comment: do ur calls inside ionviewdidload method inside componet A

Comment: hmmm.. maybe checking the database in a ionViewWillEnter on component A?

Comment: yes,its also fine

Comment: thank you so much, it worked with the WillEnter! ..I was searching a solutin for hours!

Comment: welcome, i will update as answer so that it may usefull for needed one in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ionic own Lifecycle events will fit for your requirements,like `ionViewDidLoad()`,`ionViewWillEnter()`,`ionViewWillLeave()`,`ionViewDidLeave()`,`ionViewWillUnload(`)

Comment: These all life cycles related to ionic version 3 , am i wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are achiving to do is the communication between parent and child component wich is pritty easy to do with AfterViewInit implementation of the component A:

```
export class A implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{
@Input() SharedValue = {}
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this.B) {
            this.SharedValue= this.B['sharedValue'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What this implies is that A is parent of B and both have a SharedValue input

Comment: thanks for the angular version,  Sa E Chowdary gave an answer based on Ionic

Comment: in my case, A and B are sibillings... does it make a difference?

Comment: Yes! The parent of the siblings should implement the code i provided.